# Java: CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() do no invoke asynchronous method

Tags: java, future, completable-future

let us assume following main method:

```
public class Async {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Async::sendMsg);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());


    }

    public static String sendMsg() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want just make a asynchronous call without blocking the main-Thread. But the console outputs only following string:

```
main
```

Outputs of `sendMsg`-method seems not to be invoked. But why? Have i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) uses the [common ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) in which tasks are automatically terminated once the program (the main thread) terminates.

Comment: Is there a simple workaround ?

Comment: Capture the `CompletableFuture` returned from the call to `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`. Then, after the `System.out.print....` statement, call `future.get()`. Your main thread will then wait until the background thread finishes running as well.

Comment: But future.get() blocks the main-Thread...

Comment: @user3133542 that's correct. For the simple code you posted, it will work and you'll see both threads print their name. If there's another scenario you have in mind, please share so we may help you.